# String matching balanced pairs of braces

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am trying to extract from a string in *Mathematica* all instances of

```
\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}
```

Where `ABC` and `DEF` are general expressions that may contain matching `{` and `}`.

Clearly, if `ABC` and `DEF` do not contain `{` or `}` the following *Mathematica* command will do the job:

```
StringCases[string, 
 Shortest["\\newcommand{" ~~ __ ~~ "}{" ~~ __ ~~ "}"]]
```

as can be seen as applied to

```
string = "asdkashdkj\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}asdahgsjagsd\\newcommand{\
ABC}{DwewEF}ahgdajhdgj\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}";
```

unfortunately, once `ABC` or `DEF` get more complex, e.g.:

```
string = "\\newcommand{ABC{asdas}{asdsad}}{DEF}";
```

I no longer get what I want, which would be `\\newcommand{ABC{asdas}{asdsad}}{DEF}`.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I am getting the exact output you want. (Mathematica v9)

Comment: @belisarius Strange. I'm getting `{"\\newcommand{ABC{asdas}{asdsad}"}` for second `strnig` in v8.0, 9.0, 10.0 and 10.1.

Comment: Related: [(5776158)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5776158/618728), [(45829)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45829/121)

Comment: Related: [How can I read in specific information from a TeX-file?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4892/14303)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can test whether braces are balanced with something like (version [simplified by Guess who it is.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87329/string-matching-balanced-pairs-of-braces/87333#comment237653_87333)):

```
ClearAll[balancedBracesQ]
balancedBracesQ[str_String] := StringCount[str, "{"] === StringCount[str, "}"]
```

And use it in string pattern in following way:

```
StringCases[
    "a\\newcommand{ABC{asdas}{asdsad}}{DEF{x}y}asdkashdkj\
\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}asdahgsjagsd\\newcommand{ABC}{DwewEF}ahgdajhdgj\
\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}"
    , 
    Shortest[
        "\\newcommand{" ~~ (arg1__ /; balancedBracesQ[arg1]) ~~ 
        "}{" ~~ (arg2__ /; balancedBracesQ[arg2]) ~~ "}"
    ]
]
(* {
    "\\newcommand{ABC{asdas}{asdsad}}{DEF{x}y}",
    "\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}",
    "\\newcommand{ABC}{DwewEF}",
    "\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}"
} *)
```

---

Since useless benchmarks are always fun, let's make some.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

ClearAll[testedFunctions, "Global`extractNewCommnad*"]

extractNewCommnadOP[str_String] := StringCases[str, Shortest["\\newcommand{" ~~ __ ~~ "}{" ~~ __ ~~ "}"]]
extractNewCommnadWReach[str_String] := StringCases[str, RegularExpression["\\\\newcommand({([^{}]|(?1))*})(?1)"]]
With[{balancedBracesQ = StringCount[#, "{"] === StringCount[#, "}"] &},
    extractNewCommnadJkuczm[str_String] := StringCases[str, Shortest["\\newcommand{" ~~ (arg1__ /; balancedBracesQ[arg1]) ~~ "}{" ~~ (arg2__ /; balancedBracesQ[arg2]) ~~ "}"]]
]
extractNewCommnadAmr[str_String] := Cases[Characters[str] //. {{a___, "{", inside : Except["{" | "}"] ..., "}", b___} :> {a, \[BlackKing][inside], b}, Flatten[{a___, Characters["\\newcommand"], in1_\[BlackKing], in2_\[BlackKing], b___}] :> {a, \[WhiteQueen][in1, in2], b}} /. {\[BlackKing] -> ("{" <> StringJoin[##] <> "}" &), \[WhiteQueen] -> NewCommand}, nc_NewCommand :> "\\newcommand" <> nc[[1]] <> nc[[2]]]

testedFunctions = Symbol /@ Names["Global`extractNewCommnad*"];
```

Number of occurrences of searched pattern:

```
BenchmarkPlot[Select[testedFunctions, #@"\\newcommand{x}{y}\\newcommand{x}{y}" === {"\\newcommand{x}{y}", "\\newcommand{x}{y}"} &], StringRepeat["\\newcommand{x}{y}", #] &]
```

[image: repeated occurrences benchmark]

Length of argument of "newcommand":

```
BenchmarkPlot[Select[testedFunctions, #@"\\newcommand{xx}{y}" === {"\\newcommand{xx}{y}"} &], "\\newcommand{" <> StringRepeat["x", #] <> "}{y}" &]
```

[image: argument length benchmark]

Number of braces pairs inside "newcommand" argument:

```
BenchmarkPlot[Select[testedFunctions, #@"\\newcommand{{x}}{{y}}" === {"\\newcommand{{x}}{{y}}"} &], "\\newcommand{" <> StringRepeat["{x}", #] <> "}{" <> StringRepeat["{y}", #] <> "}" &]
```

[image: nested braces benchmark]

Number of braces pairs outside of "newcommand":

```
BenchmarkPlot[Select[testedFunctions, #@"\\newcommand{x}{y}{z}" === {"\\newcommand{x}{y}"} &], "\\newcommand{x}{y}" <> StringRepeat["{z}", #] &]
```

[image: string length benchmark]

Clearly [WReach's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87349/14303) wins hands down.

Comment: `StringCount[str, "{"] == StringCount[str, "}"]` looks much more straightforward, no?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great!

Comment: @J.M. It sure does.

Comment: I must point out that this only works if brackets are always in order and are never nested, e.g. it fails on `")("`, `")()("`, `"))(("`, `")()(()"`, etc.

Answer (score 10):

I suppose that the set of answers won't be complete without the contribution of a cryptic `RegularExpression`...

```
$pattern = RegularExpression["\\\\newcommand({([^{}]|(?1))*})(?1)"];
```

The pattern works for simple cases:

```
StringCases[#, $pattern]& @
  "XXX\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}XXX\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}XXX\\newcommand{MNO}{PQR}"

(* { "\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}",
     "\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}", 
     "\\newcommand{MNO}{PQR}" } *)
```

... and more complicated cases:

```
StringCases[#, $pattern]& @
  "\\newcommand{XXX{ABC}XXX{DEF}XXX}{XXX{GHI}XXX}\\newcommand{JKL}{MNO}\\oldcommand{XXX}"

(* { "\\newcommand{XXX{ABC}XXX{DEF}XXX}{XXX{GHI}XXX}",
     "\\newcommand{JKL}{MNO}" } *)
```

... and even cases with nested occurrences:

```
StringCases[#, $pattern]& @
  "\\newcommand{ABC}{\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}}\\oldcommand{XXX}{XXX}"

(* { "\\newcommand{ABC}{\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}}" } *)
```

If desired, we can use `Overlaps -> True` to extract those nested cases as well:

```
StringCases[#, $pattern, Overlaps -> True]& @
  "\\newcommand{ABC}{\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}}\\oldCommand{XXX}{XXX}"

(* { "\\newcommand{ABC}{\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}}",
     "\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}",
     "\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}" } *)
```

**What Does All This Gibberish Mean?**

Let's consider the pattern in detail:

```
RegularExpression["\\\\newcommand({([^{}]|(?1))*})(?1)"]
```

`\\\\` matches a single backslash.  The desired single backslash is escaped once to account for *Mathematica* string syntax.  Each resulting backslash must then be escaped a second time to account for regular expression syntax.  Thus we end up with four backslashes.  `newcommand`, of course, matches that self-same literal text.

The main part of the pattern, in outline, looks like this: `({...})(?1)`.  `{...}` matches some text surrounded by braces.  This pattern is "captured" by wrapping it with parentheses: `({...})`.  This pattern is then re-used by inserting a back-reference to it: `(?1)`.  The significance of the *1* is that it is referencing the #1 (i.e. first) capture group.  Note that `(?1)` does not refer to the text matched by the first pattern, but rather it refers to the pattern itself.  The construction will match different text from the first occurrence, but according to the same pattern.

Now let's return to the subpattern which we elided above: `([^{}]|(?1))*`.  This defines a second capture group containing alternatives which can be repeated zero or more times, `(...|...)*`.  Each occurrence must be either a non-brace character (`[^{}]`) or any text that matches that outer pattern #1 that we captured earlier.

Purists will note that we do not need to capture these inner alternatives, so the inner group should really be expressed as a non-capturing group, `(?:...)*`.  This detail is largely irrelevant in practice, so I opted to reduce the amount of line noise in the pattern.

**Using Named Patterns For Safety**

As discussed in [(72724)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72724/142), using positional pattern back-references such as `(?1)` can sometimes give unpredictable results in *Mathematica*.  We can change the pattern to use named back-references for safety:

```
$pattern2 = RegularExpression["\\\\newcommand(?P<x>{([^{}]|(?P>x))*})(?P>x)"];

StringCases[#, $pattern2, Overlaps -> True]& @
  "\\newcommand{ABC}{\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}}"

(* { "\\newcommand{ABC}{\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}}",
     "\\newcommand{DEF}{\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}}",
     "\\newcommand{GHI}{JKL}" } *)
```

The first capture group `(...)` is replaced by the syntax `(?P<x>...)` which assigns the name *x* to the group.  Each pattern back-reference `(?1)` is then replaced with an explicit back-reference to that name, `(?P>x)`.

Comment: Excellent, I was just explaining to someone today that regular expressions are surprisingly not regular (in the Chomsky sense) at all! This was my example.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I always amazed at these cryptic regular expressions!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my possibly over-engineered, potentially incomplete approach:

```
string = "asdkashdkj\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}asdahgsjagsd\\newcommand{ABC}{DwewEF}ahgdajhdgj\\newcommand{ABC}{DEF}\\newcom\\newcommand{ABC{asdas}{asds{}ad}}{DEF}";

step1 = Characters[string] //. {
   {a___, "{", inside : Except["{" | "}"] ..., "}", 
     b___} :> {a, \[BlackKing][inside], b},
   Flatten[{a___, Characters["\\newcommand"], in1_\[BlackKing], 
      in2_\[BlackKing], b___}] :> {a, \[WhiteQueen][in1, in2], b}}

step2 = step1 /. {
    \[BlackKing] -> ("{" <> StringJoin[##] <> "}" &),
    \[WhiteQueen] -> NewCommand};

step3 = Cases[step2, _NewCommand];

Grid[List @@@ step3, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: output]

Regardless of its potential misgivings, notice how particularly *cool* this program is:

[image: cool program]