# Remove expression with matched braces from string

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am writing a LaTeX document where the custom command `\chg{...}` highlights changes in some color. Here I am, with a document of about 50 of those. Sure, one could just remove "\chg" everywhere, but after a long history of collaborative editing blocks {...{like this}} keep piling up.

Here is an example:

```
str = "We extracted \\chg{geometrical statistics \\sout{summary geometric data}} using {Wolfram Mathematica}$^\\text{\\textregistered}$ 11.2."
```

Could it be automatically adapted so that the output is:

```
We extracted geometrical statistics \sout{summary geometric data} using {Wolfram Mathematica}$^\text{\textregistered}$ 11.2.
```

Is there a way to remove `\chg{...}` but keep its arguments in place? [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87329/string-matching-balanced-pairs-of-braces) shows how to retrieve `"\chg{correct!}"` from `"finally \chg{correct!}"`, but I couldn't quite work out how to retrieve `"finally correct!"`.