# Function returning a pattern with condition - how to prevent condition to evaluate prematurely?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, hold

I figured it would be convenient to have a function
that returns a pattern, that match equally nested brackets, of the specified type. Such a pattern is easy to create, but I get some error messages, related to the condition being evaluated prematurely.
The two string-replacements below returns the expected result, but the second one gives the error message
`StringCount::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringCount[mid,{].`

**How to make BalancedBracketPattern work?**
My idea was that `HoldPattern` would prevent the conditional to be evaluated before the actual pattern is used, but that did not work.

Even better, make it only match the stuff inside the brackets!

```
BalancedBracketPattern[left_: "{", right_: "}"] :=
    HoldPattern[
   Shortest[left ~~ mid___ ~~ right] /; 
    StringCount[mid, left] == StringCount[mid, right]];

str = "{{abc}{def}}{blah-blah}";

StringReplace[str, 
 w : (Shortest["{" ~~ mid___ ~~ "}"] /; 
     StringCount[mid, "{"] == StringCount[mid, "}"]) :> f[w]]

StringReplace[str, w : BalancedBracketPattern[] :> f[w]]
```

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @CarlWoll I am using 11.3.0.0

Comment: I don't get error messages for your second example. Perhaps you have lingering definitions? Try doing `ClearAll[BalancedBracketPattern]` and then repeating your code.

Comment: Ah, you are correct! Is there some way to modify the code, so that it only matches the stuff inside the brackets then?

Comment: related: [String matching balanced pairs of braces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87329/142)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to match only the stuff inside the brackets (otherwise, it is equivalent to the approach in the question):

```
Attributes[BalancedBracketPattern] = {HoldFirst};
Module[
 {defName},
 Quiet[
  BalancedBracketPattern[name_Symbol: defName, left_: "{", right_: "}"] :=
    Shortest[
     left ~~ (name___) ~~ right /;
      StringCount[name, left] == StringCount[name, right]
     ];,
    RuleDelayed::rhs
  ]
 ]

str = "{{abc}{def}}{blah-blah}{12{12}{}124}";
StringReplace[str, BalancedBracketPattern[w] :> f[w]]
```

A few notes:

- We set the [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) attribute to have the same behaviour as [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html)
- We localize `defName` using `Module` to ensure that we're using a unique symbol for the default name of the pattern
- We use [`Quiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) to suppress the [`RuleDelayed::rhs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Rule/rhs.html) warning that is generated because we're using the argument as a pattern name.
- Restricting `name` to `_Symbol` not only makes the function more foolproof, it also allows omission of the pattern name while still specifying different brackets, as e.g. in `BalancedBracketPattern["{", "}"]`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, that almost works as I want:

```
BalancedBracketPattern[left_: "{", right_: "}"] := Module[{f},
   f[m_String] := StringCount[m, left] - StringCount[m, right];
   (Shortest[left ~~ mid___ ~~ right /; f[mid] == 0])
   ];
str = "{{abc}{def}}{blah-blah}{12{12}{}124}";
StringReplace[str, w : BalancedBracketPattern[] :> f[w]]
```

This returns

```
f["{{abc}{def}}"] ~~ f["{blah-blah}"] ~~ f["{12{12}{}124}"]
```

I would like to modify the function so that the return value of the above is instead

```
f["{abc}{def}"] ~~ f["blah-blah"] ~~ f["12{12}{}124"]
```

so that the pairs of matching brackets are also (automatically) removed.

Comment: Why not use `StringReplace[str, w : BalancedBracketPattern[] :> f[StringTake[w, {2, -2}]]]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Sure, that works, but I find it a bit ugly or inconvenient. If there is a better way to do it, I would like to know, but perhaps it is not possible